# $N^{th}$ root of a sequence converges to the same limit.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, cauchy-sequences

I need to prove that for a sequence  $\{a_n\}$   of positive numbers such that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$. Show $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(a_1a_2\ldots a_n)}= L$. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n] x=1$ for all  constant $x\gt0$

Comment: If you take logarithms, it reduces to an arithmetic-mean fact that you've probably seen already.

Comment: Thanks for help @GregMartin. But I need to prove it without using logarithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $\epsilon>0.$ Then there exists $N$ such that $a_n<L+\epsilon$ for $n>N.$ Thus

$$(a_1a_2\dots a_n)^{1/n}= (a_1a_2\dots a_N)^{1/n}(L+\epsilon)^{(n-N)/n}.$$

Take the $\limsup$ as $n\to \infty$ to see

$$\limsup (a_1a_2\dots a_n)^{1/n}\le 1\cdot (L+\epsilon).$$

This shows $\limsup(a_1a_2\dots a_n)^{1/n}\le L.$

Comment: You also need to do lim inf and L=0.

Comment: @martycohen Right. It was just a hint though.

Answer (score 0):

The only limit needed
is that
$\lim_{n \to \infty} a^{1/n}
= 1
$
for any $a > 0$.
Here's a proof of that from
"What is Mathematics"
that only uses
Bernoulli's inequality
$(1+x)^n
\ge 1+nx$
for
$x > 0, n \ge 1$.

If $a > 1$
let $b = a-1$
so $b \gt 0$
and
$a^{1/n} = 1+c$.
Then
$a
=1+b
=(1+c)^n
\ge 1+nc
\gt nc
$
so
$c < \dfrac{a}{n}$
so $a^{1/n}-1
\lt \dfrac{a}{n}
$.

Similarly,
if $0 < a < 1$,
then
$a = \dfrac1{1+b}$
where
$b = \dfrac1{a}-1 > 0$.
If $1+c = (1+b)^{1/n}$
then
$1+b
=(1+c)^n
\ge 1+nc
\gt nc
$
so
$c
\lt \dfrac{1+b}{n}
=\dfrac1{an}
$
so
$a^{1/n}
=\dfrac1{(1+b)^{1/n}}
=\dfrac1{1+c}
$
and
$1-a^{1/n}
=1-\dfrac1{1+c}
\lt 1-\dfrac1{1+\dfrac1{an}}
= 1-\dfrac{an}{an+1}
= \dfrac{1}{an+1}
$.

In both cases
$a^{1/n}-1 \to 0$.

Now,
the main attraction.

Let
$A_n
=\prod_{k=1}^n a_k$.

If $L = 0$,
for any $c > 0$
there is a $n(0)$ such that
$|a_n| < c$ for $n \ge n(0)$.
Then,
for $n > n(0)$,

$\begin{array}\\
|A_n|
&=|\prod_{k=1}^n a_k|\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n |a_k|\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n |a_k|\\
&\le\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n c\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|c^{n-n(0)}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|}{c^{n(0)}}c^{n}\\
&=p(c)c^{n}
\qquad p(c) = \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|}{c^{n(0)}}\\
\text{so}\\
|A_n|^{1/n}
&\le (p(c))^{1/n}c\\
&\le 2c
\qquad\text{for large enough } n\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
for any $c > 0$
$|A_n|^{1/n}
\le 2c$
for all large enough $n$,
so
$\lim_{n \to \infty} |A_n|^{1/n}
=0$.

For $L > 0$
we do the same decomposition
of the product
but with different bounds.

If $L > 0$ then,
for any $c > 0$
such that $c < L/2$,
there is a $n(c)$ such that
$L-c < a_n < L+c$
for $n > n(c)$,
or
$1-\frac{c}{L} < \frac{a_n}{L} < 1+\frac{c}{L}$
or
$1-d < \frac{a_n}{L} < 1+d$
where $d = \frac{c}{L}
$.

Then,
for $n > n(0)$,

$\begin{array}\\
|A_n|
&=|\prod_{k=1}^n a_k|\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n |a_k|\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n |a_k|\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{|A_n|}{L^n}
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n |a_k|}{L^n}\\
&=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|}{L^{n(0)}}\dfrac{\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n |a_k|}{L^{n-n(0)}}\\
&=p(c)\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n \dfrac{|a_k|}{L}
\qquad p(c) = \dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{n(0)} |a_k|}{L^{n(0)}}\\
&\text{Now we get upper and lower bounds}\\
\dfrac{|A_n|}{L^n}
&=p(c)\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n \dfrac{|a_k|}{L}\\
&\lt p(c)\prod_{k=n(0)+1}^n (1+d)\\
&= p(c)(1+d)^{n-n(0)}\\
&= \dfrac{p(c)}{(1+d)^{n(0)}}(1+d)^{n}\\
&= q(c)(1+d)^{n}
\qquad q(c) = \dfrac{p(c)}{(1+d)^{n(0)}}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{|A_n|^{1/n}}{L}
&< \sqrt[n]{q(c)}(1+d)\\
&< (1+d)(1+d)
\qquad \text{for large enough } n\\
&=(1+d)^2\\
\end{array}
$

Since we can choose
any $d > 0$
by making
$c = Ld$,
$\lim\sup \dfrac{|A_n|^{1/n}}{L}
\le 1
$.

Similarly,
using the lower bound for
$\dfrac{a_n}{L}$,
we can show that
$\lim\inf \dfrac{|A_n|^{1/n}}{L}
\ge 1
$.

Therefore
$\lim_{n \to \infty}= \dfrac{|A_n|^{1/n}}{L}
= 1
$.